# arecord only works with -D

Tags: audio, linux, usb-audio, arecord

Long story short, my mic was working fine yesterday. I then had a pair of USB speakers connected and then again disconnected. And now I cannot get the little thing to do a arecord with using the "-D" parameter.

My setup is currently a monitor with HDMi and sound output (works perfectly), 1 USB mic (did work fine, but now doesnt).

`**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

`**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

alsa.conf:

`defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.pcm.device 0`

cat /proc/asound/cards

`0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
 1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
                      C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2, full s`

My ~/.asoundrc

pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

I am fairly new to this so I might have missed something obvious, but any pointers are appreciated.df

Comment: your title says it *only works with -D* - but the body of the question states *cannot get the little thing to do a arecord with using the "-D" parameter.* and then there is no example of using `-D` anywhere - so, confused

Comment: ahh forgot to add it :P

I have been doing some ts since, so I cant even replicate the issue anymore, though I have gotten it narrowed down to it being a problem with the mic not being set up correctly.
Which is weird as it was working perfectly fine right after I installed it, but after I had some usb powered speakers connected it messed up my mic it seems..